# Messaging на основе faye

Tags: node.js

Я делаю messaging на основе faye (node.js). Как я могу получить все сообщения с канала?
То есть пользователь заходит, и ему выводятся все сообщения с канала, которые были опубликованы до того, как он зашел?

Answer (score 1):

Храните пулл последних событий (например, 100) в faye-сервере и на subscribe отправляйте их клиенту, который сейчас подписывается.

Comment: Можно пример кода или линк на информацию, я новичок в этом.